# Does jobs scheduled in crontab in VM still executes even if the system is shut down?

Tags: bash, scripts, shutdown, cron, virtualization

I had scheduled a job in crontab around 9 am and thought it would execute it accordingly . Later , after one hour or so , I started my system to check if it's been done or not. But it wasn't done.

Does that mean I need to turn my system on before the particular task has been scheduled in crontab in order to get it completed on its own ?

Answer (score 1):

The system must be operating for cron to work.

From `man cron`:

```
  cron  then wakes up every minute, examining all stored crontabs, check‐
  ing each command to see if it should be  run  in  the  current  minute.
```

Cron is NOT clever enough to discover missed jobs due to poweroff.

Instead, use anacron or systemd timers on systems that get powered off to run jobs after restart.